# How to keep the session alive within WebSocket in Dart?

Tags: javascript, session, dart

HttpSession's lastSeen is updated only if there is a new request. However, in my environment, I have a WebSocket connection and I'd like to keep the session alive as long as the Web connection is alive. But, I can't find a right method to do it.

> Firing another HTTP request periodically could be a solution, but I'm looking for something that can be done within the WebScoket's handler.
>
> Note: the WebSocket connection won't be closed. Rather, the session can be timed out. It means `request.session` can return a different instance when processing one WebSocket message.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the WebSockets already have support for ping control frames to keep the connection alive. See [The official spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#page-37).

As far as I can tell I have never seen an WebSocket to be closed early.

Comment: WebSocket won't be closed, but session is timed out (and re-created if accessed again). From source code, _HttpSession._markSeen is called only when a new _HttpRequest instance is created. You can check _HttpSession.lastSeen never changes even if you have a busy WebSocket connection.